# Why does the following code not work?

Tags: java

I am wondering for 2 hours now why this code doesn't produce the expected results. 
If I enter 3 integers, say 3, 4 and 5, it should give me all 27 possible sums (given that the numbers can be positive, negative or zero.)

So it should produce the following:

-3-4-5 = **-12**

-3-4+0 = **-7**

-4-4+5 = **3**

and so on...

```
  int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
  int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
  int c = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

  for (int k = -4; k <= -2; k++)
     for (int i = -4; i <= -2; i++)
        for (int j = -4; j <= -2; j++)
       {  

         if (k == -4)
           a = -a;
         else if(k == -3)
           a = 0;
         else 
            a = a;

        if (i == -4)
           b = -b;
         else if(i == -3)
           b = 0;
         else 
           b = b;


        if (j == -4)
           c = -c;
         else if(j == -3)
           c = 0;
         else 
            c = c;

         System.out.println(a + b + c);
     }
```

Comment: `Why doesnt the code work` doesnt work how? What does it currently do?

Comment: I suggest you step through your code in your debugger so you understand exactly what your code is doing. Why doesn't it work? because it doesn;'t make any sense. For example if you change `a` it will stay changed until you change it again so if you assign it to `a = 0` it will stay `0` and `a = a;` doesn't do anything.

Comment: I suggest you change the name of your question to something more identifiable. `Why does the following code not work?` is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be modifying `a`, `b` or `c` as this will only mean you can't use this value after the first loop.  You want to explore what happens when you add, subtract or ignore each value.  This is the same as multiplying it by +1, -1 or 0.

In short.

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
int c = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

for (int ma = -1; ma <= +1; ma ++)
  for (int mb = -1; mb <= +1; mb ++)
    for (int mc = -1; mc <= +1; mc ++)
       System.out.println(ma * a + mb * b + mc * c);
```

This will print out 27 values, though they might not be all unique.

If you have to stare at code for more than 2 minutes, you should be using your debugger to help debug your code.